# Using don't-care in enumeration typedef in synthesizable SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, synthesis

I have the following code:

```
typedef enum logic [1:0] {
  CMD1 = 2'b1?,
  CMD2 = 2'b01,
  CMD3 = 2'b00
} cmd_t;
```

Basically, if the MSB is 1, it's CMD1 (I'll use the LSB for part of the index). And if the MSB is 0, then decode the rest of bits for the command.

I then try to decode using an always_comb:

```
cmd_t myCmd;
always_comb begin
  casez(myCmd)
    CMD1: isCmd1 = 1'b1;
    CMD2: isCmd1 = 1'b0;
    default: isCmd1 = 1'b0;
  endcase
end
```

Unfortunately, I get this message from Spyglass:

```
[12EE]   W467 Based number 2'b1? contains a don't-care (?) - might lead to simulation/synthesis mismatch
```

This code should be synthesizable, no? Can this Spyglass warning be waived safely?

Comment: which line was it complaining about? it should be ok to wave it in your example, unless tehre are other usages of the enum.

Comment: BTW, you have a syntactic error in the definition of your `enum`. it should be `CMD = 2``b1?`,  `=`, not `:`. This could cause your error.

Comment: It's complaining about this line: CMD1: isCmd1 = 1'b1;

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this will synthesise correctly. I think the Spyglass message is misleading. In Verilog (and SystemVerilog) `?` means *exactly* the same as `z`. You are specifying an enum with 4-state base type values, where `CMD1` is to be represented exactly by `2'b1z`.

Comment: but this is absolutely ok if the value is used as a label in casez (as in the OP's example). It will have issues in other cases, e.g. if it appears in rhs.

Comment: It still means _exactly_ the same as `z`, even in a `casez`. It's just that `z` in a `casez` means "don't care".

Comment: true, but it will not cause synthesis issues in the OPs case.

Comment: @Serge I have tried it (not to answer this question but to answer a customer's question). I can't remember which synthesiser I would have used (probably an FPGA one), but I'm pretty sure it didn't work.